# PyGame User Input

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to programming. I am implementing a pygame that can allow users to input their name after they completed the game. The input will then be entered into a text file. How do I go about doing that ? Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad. You need to split it into several smaller problems, try to solve them each and only then, if you're not able to do what you want, you can ask a precise question. In your case, I'd try first to be able to get the name from user input. Once I have the name, I'd think about how I'd like the text file to look like. Then, I'd try to create a text file with the name I got from the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this kind of function:

```
def get_name ():
    name = ""
    while (1):
        for Event in event.get():
            if Event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if Event.key == K_RETURN and name:
                    return name
                else:
                    name += Event.unicode
```

But don't forget to handle key like "backspace", wich erase last character

```
string = string[:-1]
```

But trying to adapt this code to yours would be better.